# What is Microsoft up to next with Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

Just working away with CSS/HTML and wondering when I might "hope" to see a new IE or increased support for CSS3 and HTML5. I can't find anything about futher developments on Trident/IE apart from the mention of the [Gazzelle](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=79655)

Can anyone point me to somewhere with information on the continued development of Internet Explorer, post the current version of IE8?

Thanks
Denis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for the things you're looking for on the I[nternet Explorer dev blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/), but I'm not sure if they've talked about those things yet. If they have, they'll be there.

Comment: That Blog is a good read but as you thought there isn't anything on 'IE9' yet. I had kind of hoped that MS might move to a short dev cycle like Firefox and Chrome but Chris Pietschmann has a point below in expecting the next browser in 1/2 years time. This however i think will only perpetuate the IE downfall.

Answer (score 0):

Since IE8 was just released this year, my best guess is that a new version IE isn't due 'till at least middle 2010, but it may be more likely that it'll come in 2011. And as far as fully supporting the latest versions of CSS and HTML... Only time will tell.